# What are some of the factors that impact query performance in Grakn?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm querying for concepts in Grakn, at what point does query performance on `match get` degrade / how many concepts/variables can I get in one query without impacting performance?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 factors involved in how long a query takes:

1. How long it takes to make the query plan(s)
2. How long a plan takes to execute
3. How much reasoning is needed and how expensive that is

Keeping the number of variables low helps with (1) and (2).
The time taken for (1) depends on the number of variables in the query, which shouldn't be a problem under 50 variables.
(2) depends entirely on the nature of your query and the shape and quantity of your data.
(3) Depends on the number of rules triggered, and the number of instances that the reasoner needs to check if they match the rule(s)